# Create nested jolt on data with different number of rows

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I was trying to convert JSON data into the nested way, making nested on the combination of `practice_loc, prac_num, topId`.

If practice_loc,prac_num, and topId are the same for two or more data then they will be combined together with different S1, S2,result and additional info within subList. Else they would pass as it is with the addition of subList only.

**Data**

```json
[
  {
    "practice_loc": 120,
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A1",
    "Result": "fail",
    "Additional Info": "S1 not matched."
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "120",
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A2",
    "S2": "B1",
    "Result": "pass"
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "334",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "plumcherry",
    "S1": "A3",
    "S2": "A1",
    "Result": "fail",
    "Additional Info": "S2 not matched."
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "987",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "artica",
    "Result": "pass"
  }
]
```

Expected Result is like this will combine the data which has same `practice_loc, prac_num, topId`.

```json
[
  {
    "practice_loc": "120",
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1",
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A1",
        "Result": "fail",
        "Additional Info": "S1 not matched."
      },
      {
        "S1": "A2",
        "S2": "B1",
        "Result": "pass"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "334",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "plumcherry",
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A3",
        "S2": "A1",
        "Result": "fail",
        "Additional Info": "S2 not matched."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "987",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "artica",
    "subList": [
      {
        "Result": "pass"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "practice_loc.@(1,practice_loc).prac_num.@(1,prac_num).topId.@(1,topId)[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // practice_loc
        "*": { // value
          "*": { // prac_num
            "*": { // value
              "*": { // topId
                "*": { // value
                  "*": { // index of similar objects
                    "practice_loc|prac_num|topId": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&",
                    "*": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.subList[&1].&"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "@": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "practice_loc": "ONE",
        "prac_num": "ONE",
        "topId": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you edited/changed my expected Result, I dont require this way actually, somebody edited my question

Comment: @dracile I did. I just added the beautifier output to your question. I chang it to prev version.

Comment: @dracile Let me correct my answer